# Connect new outlet from storyboard is always nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, iboutlet

[image]I'm trying to connect new outlet from storyboard to UIViewController (by dragging), the outlet created as follow:

```
@IBOutle var button2: UIButton!
```

- without "weak" key,
  in runtime, the outlet is nil, even if I add the "weak" key by myself and reconnect it again.

Its append in all the `viewControllers` in my project, only in one project.
(there are old outlets that work, the issue is only in new outlets create)

I tried to delete the drivedData.
The files exist in the Target, in Compile Resources 
I'm using Xcode 8 yet.

any answer?

[image]

Comment: update your question with your storyboard outlet \

Comment: right click on your button2 in storyboard, if its connected in a right way you must see the connection, otherwise i can help you to connect it correctly

Comment: its connected properly, i added image.

Comment: in button2 what you want to print ? like its title or anything ?

Comment: I want to use it to send request to server, any way, for checking the button reference i printed it.

Comment: would you please run the project and post the error?

Comment: do you have any action for your `button2`.when you getting the `error` after you press the button? or before? and why is a `breakPoint` in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)



    func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("Button tapped")
    }

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya the button is nil, i cant use it

Comment: but how its possible its nil value . change the name of your button with new outlet and update your question.

Comment: thats exactly my question, how it is possible.. something went wrong with my xcode..

Comment: its append for all the new outlets i'm doing. in all if the viewControllers.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i figure it out , i delete the Storyboard by removing reference,
and then reconnected it.
[image]
I guess that something append to the file reference, so the file did not respond to any changes.

10x 4 help!